# "+y operator for yanking to clip-board, not working

Tags: vim, vi

I use `"+y` to yank to clip-board so I can paste it somewhere else. It's working fine on one of my computers but not on an other.

Both computers are Linux (Ubuntu) machines. The one where it is not working, I am connecting to it through SSH.

Does anyone know how its possible that it doesn't work on one computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you ssh into a server, you run commands on that server. `"+y` (yank text and save in clipboard) works only if there is a running `X` environment.  That's why you cannot "copy & paste" with your sshed remote server.

Comment: You can however copy & paste directly between a remote and a local Vim (1) the machine you're `ssh`-in from is running X, (2) the machine you're `ssh`-ing to has _support_ for X (but doesn't necessarily run an X server), (3) your `ssh` is forwarding X requests, and (4) Vim on both sides is compiled with `+xterm_clipboard`.

Comment: Then the remote machine probably doesn't have +xterm_clipboard installed. How do I find out if it does, and how do I add it if it doesn't?

Comment: @Ólavur to see whether vim is compiled with +xterm_clipboard run `vim --version` all options will be listed with either + or - in front of them. If this option is not compiled in(-), there are two ways to go. Either grab vim source code, run _configure_ script with `--with-x` option, and then compile/install it. The easier way however is to  uninstall _vim_ and install _gvim_ package on your system. Besides installing _gvim_ it also installs _vim_ with all x-related features compiled in.